# Показ содержимого элемента div после добавления его в коде js

Tags: javascript

Я получаю элемент по id:

```
var t = document.getElementById("1");
```

Этот элемент содержится внутри div блока, и я хочу перенести его в другой, поэтому:

```
var p = t.parentElement;
p.removeChild(t);

var y = document.getElementById("newDivForT");
y.appendChild(t);
```

Теперь я хочу, чтобы содержимое t выводилось на экран, но для этого, как я понял, надо перезагруить страницу. Но, если перезагрузить стр, то срикпт просто заново будет исполняться, что ни к чему не приведёт. Вопрос, как показать t, когда оно уже  содержимое другого блока?

Comment: _Теперь я хочу, чтобы содержимое t выводилось на экран_ - после `appendChild` содержимое станет выводиться. Кроме того, при использовании appendChild не нужно использовать `removeChild` так как элемент сам переместится

Comment: @Grundy , нет, не будет. При чём я точно знаю, что перемещение происходить, так как проверяю с помощью var h = y.getElementsByTagName("a");
alert(h[0].textContent)

Comment: будет будет, пример в ответе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

после [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) содержимое станет выводиться.

Кроме того, при использовании `appendChild` не нужно использовать `removeChild` так как элемент сам переместится.

```js
var containersOrder = {
  container1: 'container2',
  container2: 'container1'
};
var curr
document.getElementById('el').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById(containersOrder[this.parentNode.id]).appendChild(this);

});
```

```css
#container1,
#container2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float:left;
  margin-left:10px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

#container1 {
  border-color: red;
}

#container2 {
  border-color: green;
}

#el {
  width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="container1">container1
  <div id="el">click me to move</div>
</div>
<div id="container2">container2
</div>
```